# ASP MVC Database SELECT query with \r\n Line Break

Tags: javascript, asp.net, database, model-view-controller

I have a problem in MVC5 with a controller. The values from the database-table are not available.

```
        public MovieController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
```

In `_context.Movies.ToList()` is a SELECT Database call.

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var movie = _context.Movies.ToList();

    var count = _context.Movies.Count();

    return View(movie);
}
```

After the execution I get  `count = 0`  but in the database are 5 entries. I think the error belongs to the SELECT method. The Visual Studio Debugger shows this.

[image: DATABASE QUERY]

A `SELECT \r\n` I don't now where the \r\n line breaks are attached.

Has anybody an idea to solf the problem?

Comment: Try to execute this `select` on the database with sql management studio and see what you got. Line breaks are ok, they should not cause wrong result.

Comment: Youre going right, the SQL call works at the sql managent studio with \r\n. Thanks. But where the entries at the controller? :-/

Comment: Did you receive these 5 enties in the sql managent studio with the same `select` query?

Comment: BTW you can get count by using movie list `Count` property this way: `var count = movie.Count;`

Comment: @Arsen: Yes, I copied the SQL statement from the Visual Studion Debugger.

Comment: @Arson: ```var count = movie.Count()``` also brings "0"

Comment: It seems you've got some problems with configuring your `DbContext` for the Movies table as you can't receive movies list from the database

Comment: your sql is for extractor table but you count movie table. your problem not related '\r\n'

Comment: @ago: The movies table was only an example for stack overflow. I thought  the real table name "executor" that you can see in the picture of the debugger was a little confusing in the context.

Comment: @Arsen: Yes after some testing I think so, too.

Comment: I don't know, are the migrations only to build the tables and there contend, or makes it other things with the model files, too.